# Magic Link to Jon Skeet's "Stack Overflow Question Checklist"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, questions, magic-links

Many comments that I post in response to questions from new members include a friendly *"Welcome"*, followed by selected [magic links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92060/add-data-se-style-magic-links-to-comments) relevant to the question, such as:

- the [[tour]](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
- [[mcve]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
- [[help/on-topic]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
- [[ask]](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

I've added [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet)'s **[Stack Overflow Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)** to my personal *"shortlist of recommended reading for new users"*.

Currently, **http://bit.ly/ask-jon** can also be used as a shortlink to the page.

---

### I propose that **[`[askJon]`](http://bit.ly/ask-jon)** is added as a magic link for use in comments.

The link could redirect to some of Jon's valuable tips [here](http://bit.ly/ask-jon) or [here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/), or perhaps an amalgamation of his tips for posting questions.  ☺

Comment: This is already linked to from https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  If you want to direct someone to that information, then [ask] is the correct comment to provide.

Comment: And if we want to link to that specific content (since it's not the same as the *How to Ask* page), I'd prefer copying it to a Meta post (with Jon's permission) and having a magic link point to that instead.

Comment: This is an a different set of tips (which would complement "[ask]")

Comment: Linking to a 3rd party location that SO doesn't have control over is inviting problems.  Jon's site has changed URL's in the past, so nothing stopping him from changing it again.  And then someone has to remember to update the magic link.  And you also leave a trial of broken links in comments. Better to link to "How to Ask" as @Servy suggests.

Comment: @ashleedawg Again, *Jon's page is linked from how to ask*, so "how to ask" *already* has that complementary information.  You don't need to compliment it twice.

Comment: Better, ask him directly your question. [[askJon](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/15/thanks-million-jon-skeet/#skeet-bot-interface)]

Comment: You just use the `[ask]` shortcut to link to the [ask] page, which in turn links to Jon's post *and others*. I really see no need to provide a separate shortcut to an external resource here. Stack Overflow doesn't control Jon's site, there is no guarantee it will be around forever in it's current form.

Comment: An alternative would be to adopt the content of that page (potentially modified) into the site, at which point it *would* be reasonable to have a magic link.

Answer (score 9):

No. Jon's page is excellent but is not a resource Stack Overflow controls or can reasonably require to be around forever.

We already have the `[ask]` short-cut, which links to the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) help page. This page, at the bottom, already links to Jon's materials (as well as others), and is easily updated if any of those links disappeared or changed.

Comment: _"to be around forever"_ It doesn't need to be around forever, since magic links only apply to comments, which are not forever either.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It still places a burden on Jon to have to maintain that page on behalf of Stack Overflow. And I rather not have to fix all the comments that would still be around to fix that link. Jon himself would rather see the content live on Stack Overflow itself.